# How to deal with memory not being released from GPU (keras)?

Tags: keras

```
train_generator = train_generator()
test_generator = test_generator()
print "...training model"
history = []
for i in xrange(NB_EPOCHS):
    start_time = time.time()
    avg_train_loss = [0.0] * 5
    avg_test_loss = [0.0] * 5
    for j in xrange(NB_TRAIN_ITERATIONS):
        (batch_data, batch_heatmaps) = train_generator.next()
        loss = model.train_on_batch(batch_data, batch_heatmaps)
        avg_train_loss += np.array(loss)
    avg_train_loss = avg_train_loss / NB_TRAIN_ITERATIONS
    for j in xrange(NB_TEST_ITERATIONS):
        (batch_data, batch_heatmaps) = test_generator.next()
        loss = model.test_on_batch(batch_data, batch_heatmaps)
        avg_test_loss += np.array(loss)
    avg_test_loss = avg_test_loss / NB_TEST_ITERATIONS        
    end_time = time.time()
    print "[Epoch %d]" % (i+1)
    print "Time spent: %.2f seconds" % (end_time - start_time) 
    print "Total train loss : %.16f | Total validation loss : %.16f" % (avg_train_loss[0], avg_test_loss[0])
    print "  hg1 train loss : %.16f |   hg1 validation loss : %.16f" % (avg_train_loss[1], avg_test_loss[1])
    print "  hg2 train loss : %.16f |   hg2 validation loss : %.16f" % (avg_train_loss[2], avg_test_loss[2])
    print "  hg3 train loss : %.16f |   hg3 validation loss : %.16f" % (avg_train_loss[3], avg_test_loss[3])
    print "  hg4 train loss : %.16f |   hg4 validation loss : %.16f" % (avg_train_loss[4], avg_test_loss[4])
    history.append([avg_train_loss, avg_test_loss])
    gc.collect()
np.save(PATH_HISTORY, history)
model.save(PATH_MODEL)
```

The following is my code. Apparently, I call gc.collect() after each epoch, however, my GPU runs out of memory at the 3rd epoch. I presume that the memory used for the first epoch should be released by the time it reaches the 3rd epoch, especially when this is a big architecture that runs for 1800s per epoch, but that is not the case. Can I know what am I doing wrong? I am using a pascal Titan X with 12gb memory. I tried with both tensorflow and theano.

Comment: Ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @Goddard Nope. Do you?

Comment: In my case I didn't close down another program that was locking up the memory.